# Apex Unit testing of Criteria Based Sharing

Tags: unit-test, data, criteria-based-sharing

I have a requirement that uses criteria based sharing.
I wish to unit test this requirement.

I have seen [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/unit-testing-sites-permission-involving-a-sharing-rule-with-unit-test-created-da) SE post that says that we can not test Criteria based sharing and I have seen the [help docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm) that also say criteria based sharing can not be unit tested. ("criteria-based sharing cannot be tested using Apex.")

However the post above is nearly 2 years old, so does anyone have a recommended approach around this to allow some level of testing of data visibility for a specific profile or public group member within unit tests?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to unit test Criteria Based Sharing so that post is still accurate, So what I would do is create a few records, and then jump from user name to user name and see if they can see the newly created record.  It's going to have to be a manual process..

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_cbs_about.htm&language=en_US